# Proof of Liminf{An} in terms of the indicator function of An

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Guys I'm struggling in demonstrating the proof of lim inf in terms of the indicator function of the sequence, which should give this result:

$\liminf_{n\to \infty}A_n$= {$\omega : \sum_{n}1_{A_n^c}(\omega) < \infty$}

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is $\omega$? $A_n$ are subsets of what?

Comment: An is any sequence such that n is a Natural number, and $\omega$ is any element of An

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All $A_n$ are subsets of some universe $\Omega$, I suppose.

As a set:

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \bigcap_{m=n}^\infty A_m$$

or $\omega \in \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n$ iff $\omega \in A_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. So in terms of indicator functions

$\omega \in \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n$ iff $1_{A_n^c}(\omega)  =1$ for finitely many $n$. (It can only be in finitely many complements of $A_n$).

And the only way a sum of $0$-$1$-valued series like in your question can be finite is to have finitely many $1$'s and all other terms $0$.

So indeed  $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = \{\omega: \sum_n 1_{A_n^c}(\omega) < \infty\}$$

is just a reformulation of the definition if you think about it.

Comment: In the second row, did you mean the limit (of the indicator function =1)?

Comment: @AkaiM no, no limit. What don’t you understand about what statement exactly?

Comment: @AkaiM No, just the value of the function on the point $\omega$. $1_A(\omega)=1$ iff $\omega \in A$ etc.

Comment: If $\omega$ is in the complement (that is, when it is =1), how can be in the limit of An?? that's what I don't understand... Many thanks